# Jersey @Valid Annotation Issue: NullPointerException at InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory

Tags: java, json, validation, nullpointerexception, jersey

I am working on a Java Jersey application where I need to validate JSON request bodies using the @Valid annotation. However, I am encountering a NullPointerException that I can't seem to resolve. Below are the details of my setup and the issue:

**JSON Request Body (example):**
This is my JSON request body which needs validation:

```
{"firstName": "f"}
```

**Jersey Application Configuration (JerseyConfig.java)**:

```java
package com.api.customer;

import com.api.customer.Exception.ExceptionHandler;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/api/v1.0")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.api.customer");
        register(ExceptionHandler.class);
        property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    }
}
```

**Controller (CustomerController.java):**

```java
package com.api.customer.Http.Controller;

import com.api.customer.Entity.Welcome;
import com.api.customer.Http.Request.UserRequest;
import com.api.customer.Http.Responses.WelcomeResponse;
import com.api.customer.Services.CustomerService;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Path("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
    private final WelcomeResponse welcomeResponse;
    private final CustomerService customerService;

    @Inject
    public CustomerController(
            WelcomeResponse welcomeResponse,
            CustomerService customerService
    ) {
        this.welcomeResponse = welcomeResponse;
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Welcome create(@Valid UserRequest userRequest) {
        String firstName = userRequest.getFirstName();

        this.customerService.createCustomer();

        return welcomeResponse.getWelcomeResponse();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.api.customer</groupId>
    <artifactId>CustomerApi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CustomerApi</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
        <jersey.version>2.34</jersey.version>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.42.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Issue Description:**
I am consistently getting a 500 Internal Server Error with the following stack trace:

```
 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [com.api.customer.JerseyConfig] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.getInstance(InjectingConstraintValidatorFactory.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.newInstance(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.createAndInitializeValidator(AbstractConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManagerImpl.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.doValidateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:518)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:488)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:450)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:400)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedAnnotatedObjectForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:629)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:590)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:880)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:283)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.DefaultConfiguredValidator.onValidate(DefaultConfiguredValidator.java:154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.ValidationInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ValidationInterceptorExecutor.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.internal.DefaultConfiguredValidator.validateResourceAndInputParams(DefaultConfiguredValidator.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205
```

I have reviewed my code and configuration but cannot identify the source of this NullPointerException.

**What I've Tried:**

1. Verified my JSON request body and controller setup
2. Checked the configuration of the Jersey application
3. Examined the dependencies in my pom.xml for any potential conflicts

**Additional Information:**

Jersey Version: 2.34

Java Version: 1.8

Server: Tomcat 9.0

**Dependencies:**

javax.servlet,
jersey-container-servlet-core,
jersey-media-json-jackson,
jersey-hk2,
weld-se-core,
junit-jupiter,
sqlite-jdbc,
jersey-bean-validation

I would appreciate any guidance or insights into why this NullPointerException is occurring and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: not much to work with here, but usually dependencies resolve this issue. i would try newer versions of glassfish for starters

Comment: @stelios.anastasakis could you please tell me which dependencies should I use for a newer version? Do you mean the jersey version? I have used Jersey version 3 also and in that case, also I have the same issue. Basically, I am running this on my Macbook M2 (is this a problem?).

Comment: Do you have a Warning in the log saying that "Lookup and initialization failed for a resource class"?

Comment: @jan.supol No I don't have that kind of warning. I see the error everytime that I have posted on the question

Comment: What is your hibernate validator version?

Comment: I have fixed it now & it is working. Seems like there was a problem with Mac M2, Tomcat 9.0. Now I am using the glassfish server & jdk 11 is working.

Comment: My suspicion was some classloading issue. The Tomcat runs each war with its own classloader. If there were the same jars somewhere multiple times, each classloader could have loaded a different jar and the injection did not happen as it should, the non-injected field was null, and that caused the NPE. Cannot imagine any other reason for the field not being injected. Glad it is working now.